# Negative regex with variable number length

Tags: regex

I would like to validate that a number who has a size between 11 and 15 characters and it's not a succession of only zero.

I have test this regex :

```
^((0[^0]{10,14})|([1-9][0-9]{10,14}))$
```

> 000000000000  -> Not matched, 
>   1501087751444 -> Matched,
>   0154564445666 -> **Not matched ?**

But it's not working when a number start with a zero. Why ?
Futhermother, `[^0]` allow alphanumeric and special characters... ugly.

Could you help me ?

Comment: How is `1501087751444` OK but `0154564445666` not?

Comment: Yes, `0[^0]{10,14}` not match `0154564445666` but works with `0azertyazerty`...

Comment: Then how did you accept an answer that will make `000000000000` invalid and 0154564445666 as valid? Looks like your examples aren't correct then.

Comment: Because it's what I want ! `000000000000` is incorrect (not a succession of only zero) and `0154564445666`is valid because is length is 13 and is not a succession of only zero.

Comment: But you wrote `000000000000 -> OK` in your question

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, It's was OK meaning is not matched, 1501087751444 is well matched so OK, but 0154564445666 it should not so KO. I was talking about the validation rule.

Comment: See this demo: http://regex101.com/r/kK1rT6 That regex matches both 2nd and 3rd string but not first and this result doesn't match with your question.

Comment: I said : "I would like to validate that a number who has a size between 11 and 15 characters and **it's not** a succession of only zero.". So the result it's what I expect

Comment: But examples in your question are not following you: **`000000000000 -> OK, 1501087751444 -> OK, 0154564445666 -> KO`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another problem with your regex: it'll not match:**0**1**0**111111111

You need a negative lookahead for this:

`^(?!0+$)\d{11,15}$`

It will make sure that there are no zeroes from start to end.

Comment: Thanks, short and it's works! But it's `^(?!0+$)\d{11,15}$` (*between 11 and 15 character*).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?=0*[^0])[0-9]{11,15}$
```

`(?=0*[^0])` is a lookahead assertion and perform only a check if there is one character different from zero.